# PHP getting Google Calendar events list "service account" (server-to-server) not working

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace, service-accounts

This code (using Google PHP API Client https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) answers "No upcoming events found.", apparently not retrieving the events since there is at least one future event in the calendar.

index.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=XXX.json');

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly');

$calendarId = 'primary';
  $optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
  );
  
  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
  $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

  if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
  } else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
      $start = $event->start->dateTime;
      if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;
      }
      printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
  }
```

I added my XXX@XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com in the list of people who can access to my calendar event details, but nothing changed. I am still trying to retrieve the Google Calendar events list without OAuth need (Service Account server-to-server).

Comment: Did you configure domain wide delegation to your google workspace account?   You also appear to have forgotten to define the user who you want to impersonate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured domain wide delegation and set subject to the user on your domain that you want to impersonate.

```
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(CREDENTIALS);
$client->setScopes(SCOPES);
$client->setSubject("User@mydomain.com");
```